# Invalidcastexception JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net

I am getting an invalid cast exception that the specified cast is not valid. On this line:

```
RootObject mountain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json1);
```

From the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) this should be fine? I can see the console output is fine?

> Response: [{"Height_ft": 2999.0, "Height_m": 914.0, "ID": "c1",
>   "Latitude": 57.588007, "Longitude": -5.5233564, "Name": "Beinn Dearg",
>   "humidity": 0.81, "snowCover": 4.99, "temperature": 63.0}]

```
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        string urlmountain = "http://removed.azurewebsites.net/api/Mountains?name=";
        JsonValue json1 = FetchMountain(urlmountain+string.Format("{0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position)));
        //below.................................
        RootObject mountain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json1); //this line
        string toast = mountain.Name;
        Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();

    private JsonValue FetchMountain(string urlmountain)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlmountain));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                JsonValue jsonDoc1 = JsonObject.Load(stream);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc1.ToString());

                // Return the JSON document:
                return jsonDoc1;
            }
        }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public double? Latitude { get; set; }

        public double? Longitude { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double? Height_m { get; set; }

        public double? Height_ft { get; set; }

        public double? temperature { get; set; }

        public double? humidity { get; set; }

        public double? snowCover { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also add your `RootObject` class definition to the question? Also a sample API call should help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The json data being returned is an array of objects, not a single object, as denoted by the opening and closing brackets `[]`.  You need to deserialize to an array or a list:

```
var mountains = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

To access the first mountain from the deserialized payload, use `.FirstOrDefault()`.

```
var mountain = mountains.FirstOrDefault();
if (mountain != null)
{
    string toast = mountain.Name;
    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Comment: I have done this however I cant access the mountains this way? I am only returning one mountain from the url?

Comment: You can safely check the payload for a record with `.FirstOrDefault()`.  Please see my update.

Comment: Forgot the `Json.ToString()` in `var mountains`, works now. +1 and thanks!

Comment: @GarrithGraham perfect, happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your JSON is an Array of objects.  You should be able to deserialize the array and get the first one like so:

```
RootObject mountain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json1)[0];
```

One thing to note is that you are sort of mixing technologies here.  `JsonValue` is from the `System.Json` namespace, whereas `JsonConvert` is from the `Newtonsoft.Json` (i.e. JSON.Net) namespace.  If you wanted to go strictly with JSON.Net, you could do something like this:

```
private RootObject FetchMountain(string urlmountain)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlmountain));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        RootObject[] mountains = (RootObject[])serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(RootObject[]));
        return (mountains.Length > 0) ? mountains[0] : null;
    }
}
```